# Cadenas y órden

Tags: python, string

Se me pide una función que identifique la letra que más se repite en una cadena dada por parámetro.
Las cadenas vienen todas en mayúsculas, pero con espacios, comas y puntos; y si hay dos letras que tienen la misma cantidad, debo retornar la letra que sea alfabéticamente posterior.
Esta es mi función:

```
 def letra_mas_comun(cadena:str)->str:
    sin_espacios = cadena.replace(" ","")
    sin_puntos = sin_espacios.replace(".","")
    sin_comas = sin_puntos.replace(",","")
    mayusculas = sin_comas.upper()
    letra_mas = ""
    letras = ""
    for letra in mayusculas:
        letras += letra
        if letras.count(letra) > 1:
            letra_mas = letra
    return letra_mas
```

Mi intento fue:

```
letra_mas_comun("Arriba roro")
Out[35]: 'O'
```

Debería retornar la letra "R", pero retorna la "O".

Comment: La función no está guardando cuántas veces ha aparecido la letra que más veces haya aparecido. En vez de eso considera que `letra_mas` es cualquier letra que aparezca más de una vez. En concreto, ya que se ejecuta en un bucle y `letra_mas` tendrá el valor de la **última** letra que aparezca más de una vez. Por eso te devuelve la O (es la última letra de la frase).

Comment: Además tal como lo tienes no es fácil añadirle la funcionalidad de detectar "empates". Creo que un mejor enfoque sería tener un diccionario en el que las claves son las letras y los valores son contadores de cuántas veces apareció cada una. Ese diccionario lo construirías recorriendo la cadena y haciendo `diccionario[letra] = diccionario[letra]+1` (si ya estaba, o dándole el valor 1 si no estaba). Una vez tengas ese diccionario buscarías en él el valor máximo y las claves que toman ese valor máximo. Si sólo hay una, retornas esa. Si hay varias retornas la "mayor alfabéticamente".

Comment: Todo se puede simplificar mucho si puedes hacer uso de `Collections.Counter`, pero imagino que no te lo permitirán.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Supongo que tienes restringido el uso de librerias y funciones especializadas.]

Esta solución sólo usa diccionarios:

```
def letra_mas_comun(cadena):
    max_letra = ''
    maximo = 0
    cuenta = {}
    for letra in cadena.upper():
        if letra.isalpha():
            if letra in cuenta:
                cuenta[letra] += 1
            else:
                cuenta[letra] = 1
            if cuenta[letra] > maximo:
                max_letra = letra
                maximo = cuenta[letra]
            elif cuenta[letra] == maximo:
                if letra > max_letra:
                    max_letra = letra
    return max_letra, maximo
```

La idea es resolver el problema en una sola pasada, sin tener que reexaminar una y otra vez la cuenta en formación.

La variable `max_letra` es la letra más usada en la cadena, y `maximo` es el número de veces que aparece.

El diccionario `cuenta` tiene por llave la letra y por valor la cantidad de veces que aparece.

No necesito aplicar reemplazos para descartar los caracteres no alfabéticos; basta con considerar sólo aquellos caracteres alfabéticos, usando la función `isalpha()`.

Por cada letra, primero actualizo `cuenta` y luego comparo la cuenta de la letra contra la cuenta de `maximo`. Se pueden dar tres casos:

1. La letra tiene una cuenta mayor, y se transforma, cambiando `max_letra` y `maximo`.
2. La letra tiene la misma cuenta que `maximo`. En este caso se comparan alfabéticamente las letras y se conserva la mayor.
3. La letra tiene una cuenta menor. Nada que hacer.

Al terminar de recorrer la cadena, tenemos la letra mayor y su cuenta, que devolvemos como tupla.

#### Demo

```
tests = [
    "Arriba roro",
    "aAabbbzZ",
    "la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta"
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, letra_mas_comun(test))
```

produce:

```
Arriba roro ('R', 4)
aAabbbzZ ('B', 3)
la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta ('A', 7)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Observación 1:

Puedes contar las veces que una letra está en un string con `mayusculas.count(letra)`, estás siendo redundante usando `letras += letra` y por ejemplo para cada letra que se repite sobre-escribes lo mismo. Solo hace falta una ejecución por letra, puedes hacerlo con ayuda de `set(string)`

```py
...
    for letra in set(mayusculas):
        if letras.count(letra) > 1:
            letra_mas = letra
```

###### Observación 2:

Además debes hacer la comparación con una memoria que te indique cual fue el número máximo previo, no comparar siempre con 1. porque en algún caso puede una letra estar repetida 5 veces y la última solo 2 veces, y la última al ser mayor que 1 remplazará a la que tiene 5 repeticiones.

```py
...
    for letra in set(mayusculas):
        if mayusculas.count(letra) > repeticionsPrevio:
            letra_mas = letra
            repeticionsPrevio=mayusculas.count(letra)
```

###### Para finalizar:

Con esas dos observaciones podrías dar con el código correcto, si quieres que tenga prioridad alfabética-reversa solo debes ordenar `set(mayusculas)` alfabéticamente para que las últimas letras alfabéticamente sobrescriban al ser las últimas. Hace falta también para que sobreescriban usar mayor igual (`>=`) en `mayusculas.count(letra) >= repeticionsPrevio:`